# Wiki pages showing approval status

Tags: wiki, approval

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and I'm new to it. I have a page library that everyone in the team can edit (wiki style). Occasionally, a page reaches the quality standards required, so it will receive an approved flag. I want this to appear on the page so viewers know the status.

To be clear, the question is how do I make the status show on the page itself to all viewers? Alongside the page content, ideally at the top.

Thanks!